# JAVA & XML : com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathException: Can not convert #STRING to a NodeList

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am writing a java function that is parsing an xml element & extracting the given xpath expression. Below is the function :

```
public static Node getDataNode(Element payload, final HashMap<String, String> namespaces, String xpathStr) {
    Node node = null;
    try {
        // Create a namespace context based on the namespaces passed in.
        NamespaceContext ctx = new NamespaceContext() {
            public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
                return namespaces.get(prefix);
            }

            public Iterator getPrefixes(String val) {
                return null;
            }

            public String getPrefix(String uri) {
                return null;
            }
        };
        XPathFactory xpathFact = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpathFact.newXPath();
        xpath.setNamespaceContext(ctx);
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathStr);
        System.out.println("Got request to process node : " + payload.getLocalName() + " with " + xpathStr);
        System.out.println(xpathStr + " has been compiled successfully.");
        ((XMLElement) payload).print(System.out);
        node = (Node) expr.evaluate(payload, XPathConstants.NODE);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    return node;
}
```

Below is the logs for this part of function :

```
Got request to process node : Body with ".//soapenv:Body/pip:request"
".//soapenv:Body/pip:request" has been compiled successfully.
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <pip:request xmlns:pip="http://xmlns.oracle.com/ServiceBusApplication/UserInterfaceTest/Pipeline">textContent</pip:request>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

I have tried different xpath expression like //soapenv:Body/pip:request, .//soapenv:Body/pip:request but still i am getting the error :

> ```
> com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathException: Can not convert #STRING to a NodeList!
>   at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.objects.XObject.error(XObject.java:711)
>   at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.objects.XObject.nodeset(XObject.java:441)
>   at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.getResultAsType(XPathExpressionImpl.java:357)
>   at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.eval(XPathExpressionImpl.java:101)
>   at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:182)
> ```

Please let me know what is wrong in the code.Appreciate your help in resolving the issue . Thanks.

Comment: Don't add clarification in a comment. **Edit** the question to clarify it. Delete the comment.

Comment: Unable to reproduce.

Comment: Hi Andreas, are you not able to reproduce ? I am still facing the problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

Unable to reproduce. Tested with [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code below on Oracle JDK 1.5 and on Oracle JDK 9.

Only change made to `getDataNode` method is commenting out the `((XMLElement) payload).print(System.out)` statement, since Oracle JDK doesn't have an `XMLElement` type.

*Test*

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
```

```
String xml = "<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n" +
             "      <pip:request xmlns:pip=\"http://xmlns.oracle.com/ServiceBusApplication/UserInterfaceTest/Pipeline\">textContent</pip:request>\n" +
             "   </soapenv:Body>";
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder domBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = domBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

HashMap<String, String> namespaces = new HashMap<String, String>();
namespaces.put("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
namespaces.put("pip", "http://xmlns.oracle.com/ServiceBusApplication/UserInterfaceTest/Pipeline");

Node node = getDataNode(document.getDocumentElement(), namespaces, ".//soapenv:Body/pip:request");
System.out.println(node != null ? node.getTextContent() : null);

node = getDataNode(document.getDocumentElement(), namespaces, "/soapenv:Body/pip:request");
System.out.println(node != null ? node.getTextContent() : null);

node = getDataNode(document.getDocumentElement(), namespaces, ".//pip:request");
System.out.println(node != null ? node.getTextContent() : null);
```

*Output*

```
Got request to process node : Body with .//soapenv:Body/pip:request
.//soapenv:Body/pip:request has been compiled successfully.
null
Got request to process node : Body with /soapenv:Body/pip:request
/soapenv:Body/pip:request has been compiled successfully.
textContent
Got request to process node : Body with .//pip:request
.//pip:request has been compiled successfully.
textContent
```

As you can see, code runs fine, but the `.//soapenv:Body/pip:request` XPath is not correct for the given XML, since there is no `<soapenv:Body>` tag *inside* the given `payload` element.